# Allow my app to be opened with camera button

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, shutter

I'm working on a WP8 app that will utilize the camera for a feature. I've read that, as of GDR2, [you can now change which app opens with the camera button](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-gdr2-camera-improvements), but:

> it appears that an app needs to be specially written to be used like
>   this; not every photo or camera app can be configured to launch when
>   you press the Camera button.

**Question:** What do I need to do in my app for it to become an available option in the "Pressing the camera button opens: " drop down when navigating to Settings -> Applications -> photos + camera?

**Additionally**, part 2 of this question would be (if part 1 is possible), when the application is launching, can I determine if the user opened it via the camera button (so that I could go straight to my camera feature)?

I've seen [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202963%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but it only describes how to use and handle the shutter button, it doesn't mention how to allow this button to *open the app*.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This thread (http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/234751-changing-default-camera-app.html) seems to suggest that only manufacturers can create apps that can do this. Not sure if it's definite, but I've never heard of a 3rd party camera app that can do more than register as a [lens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206990%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Dang. I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. I guess it makes sense, considering none of my other camera apps have been updated to include the feature.